# Astar Startup Error after upgrading from version v4.23.0 to v4.33.0

Tags: nodes, astar

Good day, everyone!

I'm running an Astar validator node.
When I upgraded the version from v4.23.0 to v4.33.0, an error occurred.

```bash
2022-11-24 02:06:57 Astar Collator
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :vサイン:  version 4.33.0-9b953e5dafb
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :ハート:  by Stake Technologies <devops@stake.co.jp>, 2019-2022
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :クリップボード: Chain specification: Astar
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :ラベルタグ:  Node name: astar
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :上半身シルエット_1: Role: AUTHORITY
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :フロッピーディスク: Database: RocksDb at /data/chains/astar/db/full
2022-11-24 02:06:57 :鎖:  Native runtime: astar-43 (astar-0.tx2.au1)
2022-11-24 02:06:58 Parachain id: Id(2006)
2022-11-24 02:06:58 Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPW97z4ZyYkd3mYkJrSeZWcwVv4wiANES2QrJi1x17F
2022-11-24 02:06:58 Parachain genesis state: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de2e3567ab0b52f4d9bca7efadf6e7b
fe0f453c356d0a7962e4227cfaefe5ab403170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400
2022-11-24 02:06:58 Is collating: yes
2022-11-24 02:06:58 [Parachain] :ハンマー: Running Frontier DB migration from version 1 to version 2. Please wait.
====================
Version: 4.33.0-9b953e5dafb
   0: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   1: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at rustc/93ffde6f04d3d24327a4e17a2a2bf4f63c246235/library/std/src/panicking.rs:702:17
   2: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
             at rustc/93ffde6f04d3d24327a4e17a2a2bf4f63c246235/library/std/src/panicking.rs:588:13
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at rustc/93ffde6f04d3d24327a4e17a2a2bf4f63c246235/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
   4: rust_begin_unwind
             at rustc/93ffde6f04d3d24327a4e17a2a2bf4f63c246235/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at rustc/93ffde6f04d3d24327a4e17a2a2bf4f63c246235/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   6: astar_collator::rpc::open_frontier_backend
   7: astar_collator::parachain::service::start_node_impl::{{closure}}
   8: <core::future::from_generator::GenFuture<T> as core::future::future::Future>::poll
   9: sc_cli::走る人::Runner<C>::run_node_until_exit
  10: astar_collator::command::run
  11: astar_collator::main
  12: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
  13: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
  14: main
  15: __libc_start_main
  16: _start
```

Parameters are set as follows.

```bash
- args:
        - '--collator'
        - '--name'
        - astar
        - '--chain'
        - astar
        - '--base-path'
        - /data
        - '--rpc-cors'
        - all
        - '--unsafe-rpc-external'
        - '--execution'
        - wasm
        - '--trie-cache-size'
        - '1'
        - '--telemetry-url'
        - 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Best regerd!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check release note `v4.29.1` https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/releases/tag/v4.29.1
In case frontier DB migration failure, please delete frontier db.

`{base-path}/chains/shiden/frontier` or `{base-path}/chains/astar/frontier`

Comment: Thank you very much.
It was successfully resolved!